# Offset of file pointer robust/reliable for several programing languages?

Tags: java, c++, io

I am having a question regarding reading files for instance in Java or in C/C++. You usually can get an offset value of the current position in file.
How robust is this offset? Assumed the file is not changed of course will I read the same line via Java as I would if using C/C++ if I position the stream on this offset?
I would guess yes, but I was wondering if I am missing something? What I want to do is making some kind of index that returns this offset value in a specific file? can that work is this offset bound to a certain API or even x-bit architecture?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The offset of a given byte in a given file is going to be 100% reliable for (at least) any system with a POSIX / POSIX-like model of files.  It follows that the same offest will give you the same byte in Java and C++.  However, this does depend on you using the respective languages' I/O APIs correctly; i.e. *understanding* them.

---

One thing that can get a bit tricky is when you use some "binary I/O" scheme in C++ that involves treating objects (or structs) as arrays of bytes and reading / writing those bytes.  If you do that, you have the problem that the byte-level representations of C / C++ objects are platform dependent.  For instance, you can run into the big-endian vs little-endian problem.  This doesn't alter offsets ... but it can mean that "stuff" gets mangled due to representation mismatches.

The best thing to do is to use a file representation that is not dependent on the platform where the file is read or written; i.e. don't do it that way.

Comment: To further your understanding how positioning works for a `std::istream` and derived types in `C++`, check out the standard or some online reference on `std::basic_istream<T>::seekg()` and `std::basic_istream<T>::tellg()`.